# Removing orders from Google Analytics Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics

I've looked through the Analytics API docs and couldn't any info on removing transactions.. Is it possible to remove single transactions?

Or is there any way to tag orders as fraudulent or test orders?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know an "official" way but if you send an transaction with an identical Order-Id it will be added to the original transaction. So by sending a negative revenue you can at least set the revenue to zero (I frankly haven't tested if  the transaction is removed if you set the revenue to zero, bit I don't think so).

Note that this will look different if you query the transactions via the API - while the admin interface will show a single transaction for an unique order id the API will report multiple Transactions with the same ID if you re-submit.

Edited to add source:

[Reverse an Ecommerce transaction](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en&ref_topic=1037062)

Comment: I've attempted this, and for some, it worked, others have bugs. When it works properly it totally cancels out the previous one, and the transaction itself disappears as if it didn't happen - no record line item, no peak no trough (it look like they've improved things in 2015). But sometimes, the line item data disappears, while the peak remains and a new trough gets created. And other times still, some information gets changed but others don't. It's weird. And because some if the information is invisible, it's hard to know what data to enter to reverse your attempted reverse transaction.

Comment: @ahnbizcad, one problem is that the second transaction might get attributed to another advertising channel. Also since these are internally still two transactions the "canceling out" only happens when you select a timeframe that includes both transactions.  In any case this is a workaround and not a nice one. If you use Universal Analytics with enhanced e-commerce tracking you can now upload refunds to cancel out the transaction revenue.

Comment: Regarding a second advertising channel, I'm actually using a blank html page and refreshing it to execute my script, so there is no chance of interaction with other tracking if that's what you mean.